# Регулярное выражение для поиска слов в тексте

Tags: регулярные-выражения, поиск, текст

Есть необходимость создать такое регулярное выражение, которое бы искало в тексте все слова с чёрточкой (например: механик-водитель, лётчик-испытатель, Санкт-Петербург, тук-тук и т. п.), но при этом исключало бы из поиска конкретные слова с чёрточкой (например: из-за, кое-как, кому-либо, по-настоящему и т. п.).
Спасибо!

Comment: Т.е. необходимость есть у вас, но сделать должен кто-то другой?

Comment: Я очень извиняюсь, но я только начал изучать регулярные выражения. И на этом моменте зашёл в тупик.

Comment: На каком конкретно моменте?

Comment: На моменте поиска слов с чёрточкой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Спасибо! А всё-таки как добавить к этому выражению список "стоп-слов"?

Нужно использовать [отрицательное look-behind условие](https://habr.com/ru/post/159483/)

Пример на PHP:

```
$text = "механик-водитель, лётчик-испытатель, Санкт-Петербург,
тук-тук из-за, кое-как, кому-либо, по-настоящему";

if(preg_match_all('~\b[а-яё]+-[а-яё]+\b(?<!из-за|кое-как|кому-либо|по-настоящему)~iu',
  $text, $m)) {
    var_dump($m);
}
```

Вывод:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(31) "механик-водитель"
    [1]=>
    string(33) "лётчик-испытатель"
    [2]=>
    string(29) "Санкт-Петербург"
    [3]=>
    string(13) "тук-тук"
  }
}
```

Comment: А как это сделать в обычном текстовом поиске (не php, js и т. п.) , например в Notepad++?

Comment: @azfita у регулярок есть несколько вариантов, конкретно тут использовался PCRE ("подвид" перл). Вам нужно `\b[а-яё]+-[а-яё]+\b(?<!из-за|кое-как|кому-либо|по-настоящему)` - вот это и есть руглярка. Два модификатора `i`, `u` - это "не учитывать регистр" и "обрабатывать как Unicode". Кроме того, тут расширенный синтаксис (отрицательное look-behind условие) - которое не везде поддерживается, а без него сделать что вы хотите, не получится. Что там в Notepad++ я не знаю, проверить также не могу, не использую. Попробуйте в этом виде, что я написал в комментарии.

Answer (score 3):

1. Находим все слова с дефисом. В PHP, например, `regex_full_match`

   `([а-яА-ЯёЁ]+-[а-яА-ЯёЁ]+)`
2. Имеем словарь "стоп-слов".
3. Исключаем из найденных слов все слова из списка "стоп-слов"

Писать сразу регулярное выражение, в котором будет список "стоп-слов" не эффективно.

Comment: Спасибо! А всё-таки как добавить к этому выражению список "стоп-слов"?

Comment: Я бы добавил отдельный метод, который возвращает массив стоп-слов. С тем прицелом, что может быть, понадобится интерфейс для стоп-слов. И каждое найденное слово с дефисом проверять на наличие в стоп-массиве